# How do I find permutations or combinations for byte?

Tags: c++

A character (1 byte) can represent 255 characters but how do i actually find it?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Please clarify.

Comment: I mean number of ways using permutation formula.

Comment: do you want to see all the possible ASCII characters ?

Comment: I want to find number of ways to arrange 0s and 1s in byte.

Comment: It's actually 256 distinct values, not 255.

Comment: @user21334 Ates is right. We get 255 because of the way computers count. Computers start from `0`, while Humans start from `1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>(answering the comment)</sup>  
There are 256 different combinations of 8 `0`s and `1`s.

This is true because 256 = 2<sup>8</sup>.
Each digit that you add doubles the number of combinations.

Comment: The general form is base<sup>number-of-digit</sup>

Answer (score 3):

In a fixed width binary number, there are two choices for the first bit, two choices for the second bit, two choices for the third, and so on. The total number of combinations for an 8-bit byte is:

> 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 2<sup>8</sup> = 256

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
for (char c = " "; c <= "~"; c++) std::cout << c << std::endl;
```

?

This should show you printable characters in ASCII proper. To see *all* characters in your font, try c = 0 and c < 255 (be careful with 255 and infinite loop) - but this won't work with your terminal, most probably.

Comment: Instead of guessing what's printable, use `std::isprint(c)`.

Answer (score 0):

8 bits can represent permutations of ones and zeros from binary 00000000 to 11111111. Just like 3 decimal digits can represent permutations of decimal numbers (0-9) from decimal 000 to 999.

You just start counting: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and then after you reach the digit maximum, you carry over a 1 and start from 0: ..., 8, 9, 10. Right? And then continue this until you fill up all your digits with nines: ..., 997, 998, 999.

It's the same thing in binary: 0, 1 then carry over 1 and start from 0: 0, 1, 10. Continue: 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, 1001 etc.

Simply counting from 0 to the maximum value than can be represented by your digits gives you all the permutations.